# Using url parameters for a page link

Tags: javascript, html, variables, web

What I'm about to ask may sound stupid but I've been trying to figure it out for a few days now. I want to generate a link to a site:

```
example.github.io/Example/Example
```

That has a variable or something at the end of it

```
example.github.io/Example/ExampleVariable
```

and then read that variable as the page loads. In a perfect world it would look something like this:

```
http://Example.github.io/Example/Example<script>function(){}</script>
```

I also need to make sure that the page the user actually goes to or at least ends up on is the original link: i.e.
`example.github.io/Example/Example` 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.


Also if anyone is wondering. 
Yes it is on github if that applies. I barely know PHP so that's not the best. It's for a ToDo list manager app I've made. There is a load function so users can share lists. The Load string (variable I'm trying to read) looks like this:
 `/LoadNAME#THEME#Item A,Item B,ect.`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using github pages you could use [URL parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). In that case the url would look something like this: `http://mypage.github.io/test/?myparam=value`

Then you could query that with javascript and execute something based on that url parameters the url contains.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use this hash `#` old trick then after it use slashes

```
example.github.io/Example/#/var1/var2/var3
```

then using the `window.location.href` with couple `split()` uses will provide you 
with an array of parameters.

```
/* URL in address bar: 
   http://localhost/test/js-url-parameters/#/str1/str2/str3/
*/

var docURL = window.location.href,
  params = [];

// filter out the website origin "example.github.io" in the OP example      
docURL = docURL.replace(window.location.origin, '');

// if /#/ found then we have URL parameters
// grabbing the parameters part of the URL
if (docURL.indexOf('/#/') > -1) {
  docURL = docURL.split('/#/')[1];
  if (docURL != '') {

    // omit the last forward slash if exist
    if (docURL[docURL.length - 1] == '/') {
      docURL = docURL.substring(0, docURL.length - 1);
    }

    // split the URL final string o get an object with all params 
    params = docURL.split('/');
    console.log(params);
  }
} else {
  console.log('No URL parameters found');
}

/* Output: 
   ["str1", "str2", "str3"]
*/
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

The above outputs all variables as `string`, so to retrieve numeric values you need to `parseInt` -*or `parseFloat()` depending on your case*.

For example, if for this URL:

```
http://localhost/test/js-url-parameters/#/str1/22/str3/
```

The above code will output **`["str1", "22", "str3"]`**, while we suppose to have `22` as integer, to fix this just add this:

```
// for each elements in params, if it is Not a Number (NaN) we return 
// it as it is, else it's a nubmer so we parseInt it then return it
for(var i in params){
    params[i] = isNaN(parseInt(params[i])) ? params[i] : parseInt(params[i]);
}
```

the above snippets go rights after the `params = docURL.split('/');` line.

Now the URL:

`http://localhost/test/js-url-parameters/#/str1/22/str3/` outputs **`["str1", 22, "str3"]`**, as you see now `22` is a number rather than a string.

[image]

Comment: Yeah it makes the URL looks a little better and a bit more "friendly", but it takes all parameters as `string` so you may need to `parseInt()` the numerical values